# How do I get Socket.io working with Svelte?

Tags: socket.io, svelte, rollup

I'm trying to get socket.io working with Svelte that I've recently started experimenting with, which is in its stock form as installed by the instructions given at https://svelte.dev/.

I'm at a loss as to why I'm getting `bundle.js:4497 GET http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N72840H 404 (Not Found)` errors no matter what combinations I try of what I had working on an earlier 'basic' Node.js server, whose relevant code looked like so:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server,{
    transports: ['websockets', 'polling'],
    upgrade:false,
    cookie:false
});
const sockets = require('./models/socket')(io)
```

I've tried numerous combinations of the above suggested in various places with alternatives like:

```
require('http').Server(app)
```

...why `.Server()` and not `.createServer()`? Nobody ever explains. I've tried with `app` and `express` and `server or app.listen` and without, some tutorials/posts have them, others do not - no idea if any of it is a prerequisite or not. Many examples have `localhost`, many do not. Sometimes with a number after the colon, sometimes not.

On the front end (in the `.svelte` file) have tried with `import io from 'socket.io-client'`, with a cdn in the index.html file and with `<script src="../socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` (no dots, 1 dot, no slash, etc) in the head. The last one was different because it wasn't found before attempting to connect with `io()`, which is where the persistent error generates.

The `io()` sometimes is suggested as `io.connect()`, or `io.connect('localhost')`, or `io.connect('localhost:3000 or 8080 or some other)`. God knows why.

Is it to do with the way `Rollup.js` bundling stuff works? I've looked around but nothing is giving any useful leads.

If my post is lacking detail or information, please say so in the comments and I will edit it to provide as much detail as is needed. Thank you!

Comment: socket.io works with svelte (and sapper). I have it working with rollup, polka, socket.io and socket.io-client.  What port are you using when you call `server.listen()`?

Comment: I've tried 3000,5000 (the localhost), 3030, 8080... it's just too random and I can't figure out what to align it to. Could you explain what difference it actually makes, because it's one of those things that I and probably many others have implemented on working versions without understand jot about it?

Comment: BTW, I have got things working by building the `bundle.js` then calling a separate `app.js` file that contains the socket.io code. So, it's working, but I don't know if that's normal or ideal. Now I'm tackling sequentially calling these in a `script` in `package.json` to try and get the convenience of `livereload` and `nodemon` working at the same time, to not have to make compromises on the way I was working before...

Comment: Have you managed to import "socket.io-client" while bundling withi Rollup? I cannot even ma this work

Comment: I keep socket.io outside of the rollup process, not tried again since first finding this workaround

Comment: With latest socket io 3.0 and svelte 3.29 I'm getting a `Cannot access 'XMLHttpRequest' before initialization` error when loading the bundle.js.

Comment: Hope it helps anyone else stumbling across this question https://dev.to/tmns/chatting-with-sapper-svelte-and-socket-io-4c6a

Answer (score 4):

1. create global store
   `export const socket = writable();`
2. add utility function

```js
import { socket } from "../../store";
import {API_URL} from "../../config"

export const getSocket = async () => {
  const script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = "/socket-3-0-0.js";
  document.head.appendChild(script);
  
  script.onload = () => {
    const client = io(API_URL)
    socket.set(client)
  }
}
```

3. invoke getSocket in _layout

```svelte
<script>
    onMount(async () => {
        getSocket();
    }
</script>
```

4. import store and use

```svelte
<script>
    import { socket } from "../store";
    $socket?.on("blah", function() {});
</script>
```

Update:

1. You can do smth like this in _layout.svelte:

   ```
   <script lang="ts">
     function getIoClient(tokens) {
       if (typeof io !== 'undefined') {
         return io(API_URL, {
           transports: ["websocket", "polling", "flashsocket"],
           withCredentials: true,
           query: {
             ...tokens,
           },
         })
       }
     }

     async function initSocket() {
       if ($loggedIn) {
         const auth = await getAuth()

         socket.set(
           getIoClient({
             id_token: auth?.id_token,
             refresh_token: auth?.refresh_token,
             access_token: auth?.access_token,
             expiry_date: auth?.expiry_date,
           })
         )
       }
     }

     async function socketLoaded() {
       await initSocket()
     }
   </script>

   <svelte:head>
     {#if $loggedIn}
       <script src="/socket-3-1-3.js" on:load={socketLoaded}></script>
     {/if}
   </svelte:head>
   ```